# Word 2010 - When printing Document appears as Vertical Letters

Tags: printing, microsoft-word-2010

I have typed letter in Word. Document looks normal. When I print, each letter of each word appears on a single line vertically. Example Below:

Words appear as  "HELP" on screen; when I print it appears vertically

How do I correct?

Comment: Could you include a photography or a screenshot of this?

Answer (score 0):

Just a guess here,
Does it print:

```
H
E
L
P
```

or does it print HELP rotated?
If it's in a table, it might have to do with your cell sizing or something?
Check your "Text Direction" also if it's rotated.

[image: picture]